# Change product name in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce

Good morning,
I need to create on prestashop the name of the product that is generated automatically based on the manufacturer, the reference, a tag in the category and color.
I found the product.tpl file. Now do I have to go change the variable name?
Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on where you want to change the name: on the product page or everywhere on the site (category, cart, order, ... you are limited to a length of 255 characters in the order_detail table).

So, if it's only on the product template, you can change the name in `product.tpl`, if it's everywhere you should consider overriding the `Product class`.

Good luck